# Trying to count the total number of paragraphs inside a blog article

Tags: plugins, functions, shortcode, blog

I'm trying to count the total number of paragraphs within each blog post but it is not getting executed and hence returning nothing.

**How do you want to use this code?**

Currently in my `function.php` I have the following code that I use to show up ads inside my post:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', '_some_func' );

function _some_func( $content ) {

    $ad_code = "the ad code";

    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 12, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }

        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Now I want to take it to next level by servicing code based on now many paragraphs are there, like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', '_some_func' );

function _some_func( $content ) {

    if( __check_paragraph_count_blog() > 15 )
        $ad_code = "the ad code";

    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 12, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

So, I tried to write the following `__check_paragraph_count_blog()` function to get the total paragraph count so that I can use it in the above call.

```
function __check_paragraph_count_blog() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
        $count = substr_count( $post->post_content, '</p>' );
        return $count;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

There are 2 problem with my `__check_paragraph_count_blog()` function:

- It is always returning 0
- It considers the `</p>` tags inside `<code>` and `<pre>` tags too.

So, if anyone can help me fix my `__check_paragraph_count_blog()` function so that it work properly it will be a really big help.

Comment: if it's not being executed you'll need to show us how it is being called before anyone can try to help figure out why it's not being executed.

Comment: @CC I've updated the code.

Comment: You're still no telling which action hook you are using.

Comment: @cjbj I'm not using any action hook. I'm just trying to write a simple function which will return me the number of paragraphs. Do I need to use any action hook for that?

Comment: If you just dump a function in `functions.php` it will be executed immediately when the theme is inititiated. This is long before WP determines which post to show. So there is no post, there are no paragraphs and the count is zero.

Comment: @cjbj so you want want me to add a filter with `the_content` and then call this function in it?

Comment: @cjbj actually I want this function to return the paragraph number so that I can use that number in other functions like `if(____check_paragraph_count_blog() > 20 ` then do that. Also I have another concern in my code that is it will count all `p` tags even they are inside `<code>` or `<pre>` tags. So, can you help me a bit brother?

Comment: I'm willing to help you, but I have no idea where that code is and how it is called.

Comment: The code is inside function.php and as I said earlier I haven't hooked it with any filter or action

Comment: @cjbj if you still don't understand my question give me 15 min and I will update my question with more details after my dinner.

Comment: @cjbj I've updated the question with all the details, please let me know if you still got any query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `is_singular()` is going to return false when you are inside the WP loop, since there are more than one posts being looped through.  Try `is_single()` or just look at the post object and examine the `post_type` attribute.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', '_some_func', 15 );

function _some_func( $content ) {

    if( __check_paragraph_count_blog( $content ) > 15 )
        $ad_code = "the ad code";
    else
        $ad_code = '';

    return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 12, $content );

}


function __check_paragraph_count_blog( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        $count = substr_count( $content, '</p>' );
        return $count;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please write a small snippet about how do you want to me code the `__check_paragraph_count_blog()` function ?

Comment: edited to show code modification.

Comment: Hey there thanks for your code. Do, I need to hook it to `wp` action or just having this function within my `functions.php` will do the job?

Comment: I believe you are calling that function from another function which is already being called by a hook to the_content.  You should probably give it a try then come back if still not working right.

Comment: Hi there, I did tried it and it didn't worked ;'(

Comment: didn't work meaning still returning zero, or something else?

Comment: didn't worked means this time I added both the test echo statement and the actual function all. Neither the ads showing up not the echo statement :(

Comment: I just noticed you were still relying on is_singular() in your calling function...see edits to my answer above; I modified your calling function as well, now.

Comment: But I want the ads to show up only for blog post not pages.

Comment: Hey it is still returning 0.http://puu.sh/qQyp4/386da94212.png

Comment: Did you also take Mark's advice and set the priority to 11 or above, for the registration of the hook and callback?  I'll again edit my answer to show you that.

Comment: Just set up the priority. I will let you know in few min.

Comment: still giving 0.

Comment: ok last shot then I'll have to code it myself in my test system...which will take longer...see edits; try passing $content to the counting function.

Comment: Yah! Now it worked. Thanks a lot. But is there any way to not calculate the `p` tags inside `code` and `pre` blocks?

Comment: Yes - there is.  You'd need to use a while loop and step through the content looking for `p` tags (instead of using `substr_count`) -- and when you detect that you have hit a `code` or `pre` tag then stop counting until you detect the closing tag for those special cases.  I think we've given you a great head start here and answered your question -- the rest is a programming exercise you should really dig into.

Comment: Hi CC, Thanks for all your help so far, can you please update your snippet with how can I skip `code`, `pre` and `p` tags under certain divs, like for example omit `p` tags under `<div class="something">`. Please. Help me out on this, if you don't mind.

Comment: ok - I really don't write code for people but I had a function lying around that works for this.  This might not be the best way to do it or most efficient, but it works.  Also, I don't like the coding style of two underscores before function names; why make them look like magic methods?  Anyway, here is a working phpfiddle with your `</p>` count function and dispensing with anything found inside `<code>` or `<pre>` tags.  Any further help on this and you should really go to stackoverflow (and put your Kevlar vest on first).  http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/m8yf-nuzi

Answer (score 1):

You first need to define what is a paragraph, is it a paragraph as being seen in the editor, or the one being seen on the html page. The distinction is critical as there is a difference of how wordpress stores the content in the DB and how it is "sent" to the html (and obviously a difference in taking into account shortcodes, oembeds and other manipulations.

In the DB itself, wordpress **do not** store the content as true HTML. Paragraphs are being separated by a new line character and not by a P tag. A filter running [wpautop](https://codex.wordpress.org/FunctionReference/wpautop) is responsible to do the conversion from a new line to the P element. If you want to be sure that you are working with the HTML version of the content you should use a priority of 11 or higher for your hook.

The other thing that is problematic with your code is that filters/actions should not be added before the `wp_loaded` hook, there are some exceptions for specific cases but even then you should not add filters in some random places in your code.

Last and not least, if you want to properly parse html, you should use an html parser and not string comparison and neither regexp. You might find it easier to actually use JS on client side then trying to handle badly formatted HTML on server side.

Comment: Hi here by a paragraph I meant those that are seen in the html page. I've also tried this approach to count but again didn't worked.
`$pattern = "/<p>.*?<\/p>/gm"; 
$paragraph_count = preg_match_all($pattern,$post->post_content);`

Answer (score 0):

If you just dump a [magic function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) in `functions.php` it will be evaluated immediately when the theme is inititiated (someone better in PHP and OOP should be able to explain how this happens, but I assume you are defining a class).

This evalution is long before WP determines which post to show. So there is no post, there are no paragraphs and the count is zero.

How to fix this depends on what you want to do. Currently you are just writing to the browser console, so [any hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) after the post has been loaded would be fine. Like this:

```
add_action ('wp', 'wpse237301_check_paragraph_count_blog');
```

Comment: give me 2 min. I'm updating my question with more clarification.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question.